# Status from wire: INVALID_LANGUAGE

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, cyanogenmod

Running cyanogenmod build:

> 11-20140804-SNAPSHOT-M9-endeavoru

When trying to authenticate with Feedly I get a toast "An internal error occurred" and this logcat:

```
W/GLSUser ( 2264): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
W/GLSActivity( 2264): [aus] Status from wire: INVALID_LANGUAGE status: null
W/GLSActivity( 2264): [aus] Status from wire: INVALID_LANGUAGE status: null
I/GLSUser ( 2264): GLS error: INVALID_LANGUAGE xxxxx@gmail.com oauth2:email profile
W/GLSActivity( 2264): [aus] Status from wire: Unknown status: UNKNOWN
D/selector.c(12665): onActivityResult: requestCode=9000 resultCode=0 intent=null
D/selector$bottom.c(12665): onActivityResult: requestCode=9000 resultCode=0 intent=null
D/storeGroup.c(12665): onActivityResult: requestCode=9000 resultCode=0 intent=null
```

Did I forget to set the language somewhere in my system?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could actually solve it by changing the system language (Settings → Language & input → Language) from `[Developer] Accented English` to plain `English (United States)`. I'm using [CyanogenMod 11](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=falcon&type=snapshot) and this special locale was set as default as far as I remember. It was [introduced in Android 4.3](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/04/16/android-localization-tips/#pseudolocalization) and is used to find potential problems in your app, whereof Feedly has at least one.